# Why Pycharm does not recognize sort for Dict, but it works on the Web playground?

Tags: python

It jumps out a traceback notice: *Traceback AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'*

And how to replace it with other code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvNoJ.png)

Comment: What is "the Web playground"? `dict.sort` does not exist in any version of Python. Unless you were using a "Python-like language" like Boo or something instead of Python, you must have had a list when you tried it there, or you must have done something different (and valid) like `sorted_hour_count = sorted(hour_count.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to `list` and it'll work:

```
sorted_hour_count = list(hour_count.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a version problem.
In Python 2 `dict.items()` returns a `list` which has a `sort` method, so this will work:

```
 sorted_hour_count = hour_count.items()
 sorted_hour_count.sort()
```

In Python 3 `dict.items()` returns a `dict_items` object which is an `iterable` but not a `list`.  You can convert it into a `list` which has a `sort` method:

```
 sorted_hour_count = list(hour_count.items())
 sorted_hour_count.sort()
```

or feed it into `sorted` which will accept any iterable:

```
 sorted_hour_count = sorted(hour_count.items())
```